# Is there any point in querying realm on a background thread and resolving a ThreadSafeReference on the UI thread?

Tags: swift, realm, rx-swift

It appears that `ThreadSafeReference` was added recently to help move across thread boundaries. Prior, according to the sources I read (which were probably not exhaustive) the recommendation to was to just query realm on the thread you intend to use the results on; effectively query it on the UI thread.

Is there a benefit to querying Realm on a background thread or does resolving the `ThreadSafeReference` basically run the query again?

Using RxSwift here's an example of this:

```
import RxSwift
import RealmSwift 


public static func getAllMyModels() -> Observable<Results<MyModel>>{

    return Observable<ThreadSafeReference<Results<MyModel>>>.create{
        observer in

        // using this queue in this example only
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {

            let realm = try! Realm()
            let models = realm.objects(MyModel.self)
            let safe = ThreadSafeReference(to: models)

            observer.onNext(safe)
            observer.onCompleted()
        }

        return Disposables.create()
    }
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance) // push us back to the UI thread to resolve the reference
    .map{
        safeValue in

        let realm = try! Realm()
        let value = realm.resolve(safeValue)!
        return value
    }
    .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()
}
```

Did I gain anything by querying on some background thread and resolving on the UI thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems unnecessary. According to the docs, queries are already being done on a background thread, as long as you have attached a notification block:

> Once the query has been executed, or a notification block has been added, the Results is kept up to date with changes made in the Realm, with the query execution performed on a background thread when possible.
>   - https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries

Answer (score 2):

ast's guidance is correct, but I dug a little more and wanted to post some extra to confirm his answer further.

kishikawa-katsumi, currently a software engineer at Realm, provided this response to the question in Realm's public slack (https://realm-public.slack.com/archives/general/p1488960777001796):

> For querying, it is fast enough in UI thread in most cases. If you're facing about a few slow complex queries, you can use background query.
>   To execute queries in the background, use `addNotificationBlock ()`.

```
notificationToken = realm
    .objects(...)
    .filter(...)
    .addNotificationBlock { (changes) in
        // The query is executed in background.
        // When the query is completed, then call this block
        ...
    }
```

> Using `addNotificationBlock()`, the query is excuted in background, when the query is completed, then call the callback closure will be called.
>   So `ThreadSafeReference` is rarely used in queries. `ThreadSafeReference` is used when you want to pass an object to another thread (for example, to specify it as a condition of a query or to use it as a parameter of an API request).

Additional information about subscribing to this block from a GCD thread (background thread) can be found here, as it requires a runloop.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841847/1060314